# Invalid output filetype

Tags: arrays, swift, avfoundation, wav, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to output a wav file from the below function, however, during runtime, I get the error "Invalid output filetype". I am confused as to why AVFileType.wav doesn't work, I tested AVFileType.m4a and it works for some reason. Cheers!

```
func createSound(soundFiles: [String], outputFile: String) {
    var startTime: CMTime = kCMTimeZero
    let composition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionAudioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!

    for fileName in soundFiles {

        let sound: String = fileName
        let url: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: sound)
        let avAsset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let timeRange: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
        let audioTrack: AVAssetTrack = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

        try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: startTime)
        startTime = CMTimeAdd(startTime, timeRange.duration)
    }

    let exportPath: String = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].path+"/"+outputFile+".wav"

    let export: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)!

    export.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
    export.outputFileType = AVFileType.wav

    export.exportAsynchronously {
        if export.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
            NSLog("All done");
            print(export.outputURL)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The preset `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` is for creating m4a files, not wav files. For wav, try the passthrough preset: `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, and delete an files leftover from previous runs:

```
let export: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!

export.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
export.outputFileType = .wav

try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: export.outputURL!)    // otherwise export can fail :(

export.exportAsynchronously {
    // etc
}
```

NB: with `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, your input audio files will probably need to be wavs too, and maybe even have the same format. If that's no good for you, then try one of the  `AVAssetWriter`, `AVAudioFile` or `ExtAudioFile` APIs.

p.s. if you're curious about which `AVAssetExportSession` preset, `AVAsset/AVAssetComposition` and `AVFileType` combinations are supported, you can use the `determineCompatibility` function:

```
AVAssetExportSession.determineCompatibility(ofExportPreset: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough, with: composition, outputFileType: .wav) { ok in
    print("COMPUTER SAYS \(ok)")
}
```

although it's basically a dry run export, minus the file-url-already-exists check and the occasionally-useful `Error` turned into an unhelpful boolean, so I guess it doesn't add much value at all.